# Conditional function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, media-queries, media

Just trying to conditionally add a function in react, i fully get it in JS but react is a bit different,

I've got my media query here

```
let query = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)")
```

so what I want to do is only allow the onClick to run if the media matches

```
<div onClick={handleClick}>
```

Cheers

Comment: So check it inside the `handleClick`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the user can resize their window at any time, run the check inside the click handler:

```
const handleClick = () => {
  if (!window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches) {
    return;
  }
  // rest of the code
};
```

Comment: thanks so ive got this :

  const handleClick = () => {

    const query = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)")
    if (!query) 
      setIsFlipped(!isFlipped);

    }
 
adding the hook inside but its not working when it reaches the size, the function does not even run at all

Comment: You said you wanted to run the handler only if it matches. But `if (!query)` will run only if it *doesn't* match. Invert your test? `if (query) {`

Comment: yes done that but it doesn't run on the media query which is weird, it runs no matter what size of the window not sure what's going on , it is responding on console.log so nothing wrong with syntax

Comment: You need to check the `.matches` property of the result to get the boolean, otherwise it'll always be truthy (a MediaQueryList result object)

Comment: ahh i see! thought so can post the syntax of how that should be written, thankyou